# 'For' loop on row with compare two columns

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have some thing similar to the below code:

```
set SelectionRNG = Range("A1:B10")

for each xrow in SelectionRNG.rows
if xrow.value(1,1) = xrow.value(1,2) do something
```

What I need to do is compare the two values stored in `xrow`.

```
xrow.value(1,1) = xrow.value(1,2)
```

doesn't work.

How do I reference each value?

Comment: Look up how to use `Range.Offset` property and iterate through one column rather than each cell in a selection

Comment: Range.offset wont work in the scenario i am using it in. i have already tried that.

Comment: no. it won't ;) `foreach(cell in Range("A1:A10")) if(cell = cell.offset(0,1))`....

Comment: ok the problem is if cell A1 B1 and C1 are all the same. when i use offset on A1 it will work. when i use it on B1 it will compare C1 and i dont want it to do that.

Comment: `For Each cell In Range("A1:A2")
        If (cell = cell.Offset(0, 1) And cell = cell.Offset(0, 2)) Then
            MsgBox "row " & cell.Row & " is equal"
        End If
    Next`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after something like this:

```
Dim rngSelection    As Range
Dim rngRow          As Range

Set rngSelection = Range("A1:B10")

For Each rngRow In rngSelection.Rows
    If rngRow.Cells(1, 1) = rngRow.Cells(1, 2) Then
        rngRow.Cells(1, 3) = "same"
    Else
        rngRow.Cells(1, 3) = "different"
    End If
Next
```

Using "Cells" you can specify 1 as the first row (of a row) and then specify the column numbers you want to compare (1 & 2 in this example) before then outputting to the third column.

If you're going to be fancy, you'd have checks on the size/location of the selection to ensure that you have a basis for comparison and a destination.